# Why Nanatsu no Taizai members didnt recognize each other at first in season #1?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I'm rewatching Nanatsu no Taizai, and many of the members (Meliodas, Ban, King, Gowther, Diane, Escanor) didn’t recognize each other at first, or they weren’t sure about the others really being who they were. Some examples,

> Ban after re-meeting King: And you, who you are?

> Diane after meeting Meliodas: Are you a holy knight?

> Escanor after meeting Ban: haven’t I seen you before?

> Gowther after meeting Meliodas and Ban: yes, I really am Gowther.
> Those traits, that posture, that scar, as I thought, you are undead
> Ban. That means the young guy whose appearance is similar to Meliodas
> is..
>
> Meliodas: that's right, I'm Meliodas.
>
> Gowther: what a surprise.
>
> Ban: and what do you think of him. I bet you'll be surprised more he's
> King.
>
> Gowther: No, he is another person

Why did this happen? Supposedly people like Meliodas and Ban didn’t change their appearances and they only separated 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

For Meliodas and Ban, I am pretty sure they did recognize each other. It's just the surprise they get after 10 years.

For King and Ban, King did recognize Ban, and Ban to King. King's hate of Ban for Elaine's death was the reason why he acted like that. Ban just doesn't care.

For Gowther, the others have not really seen him in the flesh before that moment, he has only seen King in his old fart form, and he did recognize Ban and Meliodas.

Do point out any episodes that prove otherwise. It can help move the discussion going.

Comment: Ban after re-meeting King: And you, who you are? Diane after meeting Meliodas: Are you a holy knight? Escanor after meeting Ban: havent I seen you before? Gowther after meeting Meliodas and Ban: yes, I really am Gowther. Gowther after meeting Ban:those traits, that posture, that scar, as I thought, you are undead Ban. That means the young guy whose appearance is similar to Meliodas is.. Meliodas: that's right, I'm Meliodas. Gowther: what a surprise. Ban: and what do you think of him. I bet you'll be surprised more he's King. Gowther: No, he is another person

Comment: @Pablo with the exception of Ban, which all of them knew his features probably would not change save for hair, The others don't really expect each other to not change appearance.-

Meliodas: reason being that they did not know he was a demon and practically immortal..-

King: probably the child appearance, remember that King used his big form before the parting ways...-

Escanor to Meliodas: Age..-

Diane to Meliodas: Same as how I explained..-

Gowther to King: Like explained, King changed his appearance after the parting ways.-

Comment: I take that your explanations about King and Gowther are probably correct, that's why I +1 you, the other ones sounds like guessing with no real evidence in the anime series, unless you tell me the manga says something more

Comment: @SophomoreNumberN though you didn't explain why Diane didn't recognize Meliodas. Neither of them is subject to aging (at least in 10 year interval), they were the original Sins (she was the first one Meliodas met, with the exception of Merlin) and she also had like a huge crush on him. So how could she confuse him for holy knight?